# Issues selecting between specific hour/minute times in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm not entirely sure what is happening, I need to find the specific times between 20:00:00 and 06:00:00 from a dataframe, initially it worked returning the desired values, but when I tried to adjust to different time intervals it returns an empty DataFrame. Now when I set it back to the original values its still returning just an empty list.

I've checked to make sure the file I'm importing from didn't accidentally go into the cloud, and the other data frames I'm creating from the original still returning valid data frames. So I'm not entirely sure what is happening at this point.

This is the code that worked initially and for reasons beyond me it just isn't any more.

```
speed_stop_dataframe = full_geo_data.loc[(full_geo_data['speedkmh'] == 0)]

stop_dataframe = speed_stop_dataframe.loc[(speed_stop_dataframe['timestamp'] > '2018-12-22 20:00:00') & (speed_stop_dataframe['timestamp'] <= '2018-12-31 06:00:00')]

stop_dataframe.head()
```

`speed_stop_dataframe` returns 117,970 rows as it should and intitially `stop_dataframe` returned approximately 116,000 rows now its empty.

Comment: Are you using some IPython IDE? Like Spyder?

Comment: I'm currently using Spyder

Comment: Restart the kernel with `ctrl` and `.`. You haven't shown how you're loading the data, so you're probably working with the post-filtered version after the first run

Comment: Just restarted the kernel, same thing happens, I load it as such `full_geo_data = pd.read_csv(data_path, infer_datetime_format=True)` , I was initially worried about the date time format and just tried to filter it as is, and it initially worked now Its not even giving me a type error which is what I would have expected.